# Get filename with High I/O read request

Tags: linux, jenkins, io, disk, disk-io

My Jenkins server is giving high read I/O of 5-10MB and there are no jenkins job is running on it.

I was able to find the process(jenkins) with command `iotop -oP`

[image: Jenkins-server]

and with `lsof -p 20874` i'm getting more than 2500 files which is very hard to debug.

is there any way where i can get the **filename** which is getting high read I/O request ?

Answer (score 0):

```
strace -p 20874
```

will show you all file operations made by that process. You can abort strace with ctrl-c. Some file is probably accessed alot and strace will show the file id of that file. Then simply

```
ls -al /proc/20874/fd
```

to see what file that file id points to.

Answer (score 0):

1. Created clone of Jenkins VM
2. Power on the clone VM and started removing plugin one by one
3. After removing **Prometheus metrics plugin - 2.0.6** the Read I/O is stable now